# Odd looking SciPy gamma probability distribution funtion

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, distribution, gamma

I have a DataFrame that has one column of large values (on the order of 1e6). When I try to fit this Series to a normal distribution I get an odd looking shape.

```
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,9e6), gamma.pdf(np.linspace(0,9e6), alpha, beta));
```

[image]

When I run the exact same code for smaller x values, I get a perfectly fine normal distribution:

```
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10), gamma.pdf(np.linspace(0,10), 5));
```

[image]

So, whats up?

Comment: Your second plot is not a normal distribution.  Be careful when using technical terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is just fine, simply `linspace` is not continuous, it is just a **sample** of your x axis, if you want nice distribution for

```
np.linspace(0,9e6)
```

change it so it has lots of samples

```
np.linspace(0, 9e6, 10e5)
```